# How to understand how this find with while loop works in Bash

Tags: bash, find, basename

How can I understand this syntax a bit better?

```
find ~/Documents/project/updates -type d -name "Branch*[0-9]" -maxdepth 1 -mtime -2 -print |\
while read path; do
    dir_name=$(basename $path)
    function_call $dir_name
done
```

Comment: This might help: http://explainshell.com/

Comment: So, what I wanted to confirm is path obtained from find command would be passed to while? I didnt get what path is as variable would be $path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate list of directories with [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

   - `~/Documents/project/updates` look for directories under this path
   - `-type d` look only for "directories" (and not files, inodes, or other file types)
   - `-name "Branch*[0-9]"` look only for directories whose names match this wildcard
   - `maxdepth 1` don't look any lower than one level deep
   - `-mtime -2` modification time -2 days
2. Now that we have a list, for each item in that list,

   - `dir_name=$(basename $path)` Set "dir_name" to the [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) of the directory
   - `function_call $dir_name` Call "function_call" with "$dir_name"

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Temporarily add `set -xv` to the top of your shell script and observe the results :)